# Can't override margin-bottom from navbar on bootstrap with my own css

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

I've tried to change on navbar, the margin-bottom that is 20px.

```
.navbar {
     position: relative;
     min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

This error occurred when I've tried to put an empety content. So, to solve this I use in  my css, !important:

```
.navbar1{
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        position: absolute;
        min-height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
```

and added on the index page the navbar1 on the class:

```
<div class="navbar navbar1 navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
```

How ever, the !important override the margin-bottom: 20px but it still keeps active, i've tried with div.navbar1 but it's the same problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: any online demo or fiddle demo available??

Comment: please make a demo like fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Do you load it in 2 seperated css files? If yes your overwrite have to be loaded at last.

But I think it is better to overwrite it directly with modifying the .navbar attributes.
So make a new css file for your overwrites load it behind the bootstrap.css and than put in your overwrites:

```
.navbar{
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And delete the navbar1 in html. This works for me every time I modify the bootstrap css.

Comment: My override is at last:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Medionics/index.css">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/Bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: But I have already founded the error,it was becauseof the position of other things that i used px instead of % and check that trought the resolution of my monitor

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget that margin may overlap one another. maybe the margin-bottom that you see isn't because of your `div`. Please inspect the element (Right click -> Inspect Element) and go to "Box Model" or "Layout" tab to see there the real margin of this specific `div`.
A code sample will really help us (use http://jsbin.com or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the **margin-bottom** in bootstrap is assigned to `ol` and `ul` elements, not the `nav` or `navbar` classes, which is why this didn't work.
So, instead of adding `"margin-bottom: 0px !important;"` to `.navbar`, try assigning it to an `ol` or `ul` element.

Also, if all goes well and the css file is linked after the bootstrap file, the *!important* is no longer neccessary.

Comment: I have the same issue using bootstrap 3 and the margin is indeed associated with `navbar`, not `ol`/`ul` as you mentioned